# Performance of the Cursor in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

In SQL Server I am using a cursor in my proc but it is slowing down performance.

Is there an alternative method?

Comment: The alternative to a cursor (which is procedural, row-by-agonizing-row processing) is to **think in sets** - use a set-based approach that's much more natural to SQL Server. Read [Joe Celko's Thinking in Sets](http://www.amazon.com/Joe-Celkos-Thinking-Sets-Management/dp/0123741378)

Comment: If there are alternatives to cursors that are faster depends on what you are trying to do. What are you trying to do with the cursor?

Comment: Cursors are almost always your worst choice, http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you're trying to achieve. There needs to be more info (and code) included in your question but... [CTEs (Common Table Expressions)](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/) can often be used instead of cursors. Here's another [link to an article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/avoiding-cursors-with-sql-server-2005/412) about (and how to) avoiding cursors. And [a nice. clean example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/transactsql/thread/4aa613e1-9a47-413b-9a15-77fbce2a05fe) from a forum post.

Comment: I just added another link. It's a quick and simple example.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few alternatives to cursors, but depending on what's happening within your cursor and how you've constructed it, it may not be why your procedure is slow.

If you provide some SQL we could better gauge the problem you're having.

One way to eliminate cursors is use a loop:

```
DECLARE @Index int = 1
DECLARE @Count int
SELECT @Count = COUNT(1) FROM YourSource
WHILE @Index < @Count
BEGIN
    -- e.g. Select data from your source whose ID = @Index into 
    -- a table variable or local variables

    -- Do work with your data

    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END
```

Comment: The OP's question is about performance. Although a loop is an alternative to a cursor I doubt that performing a select query every time through the loop will be more performant. Also, did you mean `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: @PaulSasik: Valid points. But since the OP doesn't want to elaborate at all, I can't really say much else. Also, `COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(*)`, there's no difference. I do `COUNT(1)` by [bad?] habit.

Comment: Agreed about the lack of elaboration. We're both shooting in the dark, as it were. But I learned something... I will never, ever use `COUNT(1)` in lieu of `COUNT(*)` ... ;-)